# How can we use group managed service account for windows containers in kubernetes

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I was able to use gMSA in docker containers using the below flag in docker run

`--security-opt credentialspec=file://myuser.json`

How can I achieve the same in kubernetes cluster?

I have multiple windows nodes in my k8s cluster. I have followed all steps as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts

or is there any alternate way to set domain user context for kubernetes containers/pods?

Any help would be much appreciated